# How to route root path / to /xyz in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, paths, routing

I am using PHP based application in which i need to configure Nginx. I wanted to forward only path / to /?product_cat=top and all other request will remains same.

below is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        server_name default_server;
        listen 80;

        root /var/www/wordpress;
        underscores_in_headers on;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH';
        add_header Allow "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH" always;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/ecom.log json;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/ecom-error.log;

        index  index.php index.html index.htm ;
        location = / {
        return 301 /?product_cat=top;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
      location ~ / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

I tried above but its giving too many redirection errors.

Comment: If the goal is to show only products from a particular category on the homepage, why not ask how to do that? It would only require a simple `pre_get_posts` filter, no redirects or Nginx required

Comment: yes the only goal is show particular categories product at homepage... Could you please help how can i do that..

Comment: **Can you edit your question to ask that instead?** Your question is asking about Nginx redirects, not changing what's listed on the homepage, say you need to change what's listed on the homepage, and you need to add `product_cat=top` to the main query. Also note that my first comment already contains everything you need to do it and mentions the filter that's the answer by name

Comment: thanks for the info..i google it and found the snippet  as below   


  ```add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_portfolio_category' );
// Only Portfolio Category
function only_portfolio_category( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
   $query->set( 'cat', '3' );
   }
}

``` but i don't know where to put these code , can you help me with that. FYI i am using woocommerce plugin and product are external affiliates.